# sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById is not refreshing feed publisher

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, consoleintegrationtoolkit

have developed a VF form and put it in a quick action & assigned it to case page layout. I am refreshing the current case tab by using console integration toolkit at submit button's oncomplete event (note that I have 30 of this command because I was unable to obtain enclosing tab id from inside quick action VF, so I refresh all open tabs)

```
var primaryTabId_0 = 'scc-pt-0';
sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(primaryTabId_0, true);
```

The problem is; console components of page layout and detail view of record refreshes successfully, but the feed actions remain unrefreshed. This VF form links an account to the case, and I cannot see this account prepopulated in one of "update case" quick actions, in the account lookup field. When I manually refresh the page or tab, this field is prepopulated.

Has this issue acknowledged as a bug yet, or is there any other code I can add that will allow me to refresh the feed view as well?

Cheers

Comment: In Spring '16 Salesforce added a parameter to the refreshPrimaryTabById method called 'fullRefresh' which will force a full refresh of the feed. Can you try adding the parameter to your function call and see if it helps? You'll need to make sure your call to include the integration.js is using at least version 36.0

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_refreshprimarytabbyid.htm

Comment: Thanks, I haven't noticed the "fullRefresh" parameter in this method. I tried setting this input to true while upgrading integration.js to 36.0 version, but record did not refresh at all. Just upgrading also prevents the page from reloading (I'm currently using a version as low as 22.0 or so). Setting the parameter without upgrading integration.js did not work as well unfortunately.